# Keep existing but push new item into array using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to build a small component which has two pieces of state:

1. An array called 'tasks'
2. A string called 'individualTasks'

Within the component, I have an input which successfully updates the individualTasks state. When the user presses on the 'add' button, I then want to push this individualTask state string into the 'tasks' array, and reset the individualTask string back to an empty string.

This means the tasks array can get new individual tasks pushed to it multiple times.

I'm currently attempting to do this through the spread operator, but I'm getting a syntax error.

Could someone tell me what the best approach to achieve this functionality is?

Here's my code:

```
const SubTasks = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
    const [individualTask, setIndividualTask] = useState("")

    const pushTask = () => {
        setTasks[...tasks, individualTask]
        setIndividualTask("")
        console.log(tasks)
    }

    return (
        <div className="subtasks-container">
            <label className="subtasks-label">Sub Tasks</label>
            <div className="individual-task-container">
                <input className="individual-task-input" type="text" value={individualTask} onChange={event => setIndividualTask(event.target.value)} />
                <button className="individual-task-button" onClick={pushTask}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Function calls must enclose their arguments in parentheses. You can't do `fn[]`, you need `fn([])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly.

You are just missing the `()` around the `setTasks` call

Change `setTasks[...tasks, individualTask]` to setTasks([...tasks, individualTask])

Comment: Thank you for the response - it's working now! :-) I never realised state hooks could be enclosed in parentheses. I always thought it had to be a square bracket. Thanks for the help, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @JonNicholson: A state hook returns an array containing the current value (`tasks` in your case) and a *function* to update the value (`setTasks` in your case). Functions are always called with parenthesis. The square brackets have nothing to do with the function, those are just the array literal delimiters and are used only because your state stores an array.

Comment: Thanks Felix - my mistake. I've never set a state hook through a function before so newbie error. Appreciate the feedback, lesson learned! :-)